# How to iterate Object of arrays from axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

there are some concepts that I am not understanding.

I have learned to manipulate objects but when it comes especially from axios I cannot get it.

This is how I am obtaining my data.

```
//Cargamos las operaciones desde la Base de datos: 
fetchData = () => {
  axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
  axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
  axios.defaults.headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Token ${this.props.token}`,
  };
  axios.get("http://192.168.196.49:8000/proveedores/api/operaciones/").then(
    res => this.setState({ DataFromApiTemp: res.data}));

    };





console.log("Datos de API: ", this.state.DataFromApiTemp)
console.log("Datos de API: ", typeof this.state.DataFromApiTemp)
```

[image]

The problem is I am no able to do the smae like this:

```
const pruebas = [
  {
    estado: 'En curso',
    fecha_compra: '2019-09-10',
    proveedor: 'GDAX',
    importe: 25,
    precio_compra: 9241.60,
  },
  {
    estado: 'En curso',
    fecha_compra: '2019-09-10',
    proveedor: 'GDAX',
    importe: 50,
    precio_compra: 9056.00,
  },

]

console.log("Typeof prueba=>", typeof pruebas)

for (let i = 0; i < pruebas.length; i++ ){
  if(pruebas[i].estado == "En curso"){
  console.log("hay", i)
}
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(pruebas)){
  console.log("key =>", key, "value =>", value.estado);
}
```

What I am missing to iterate with this object?

Comment: What is the relation between axios response and the array of objects you have posted below? Question is unclear

Comment: You should just be able to do `pruebas.map(p => console.log(p))` To log each object in that array.

Comment: `pruebas` is an array and you are using `Object.entries(pruebas)`

Comment: I would like to do the same with DataFromApiTemp. works with pruebas a not with DataFromApiTemp. This is why a posted what i use to deal with this object (pruebas) like an example.

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently have? I've run your code and have not gotten any errors. Is the resulting behavior different from your desired behavior? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
pruebas.forEach((value, key) => {

    console.log("key =>", key, "value =>", value.estado);
});
```

Also axios is asyncronous, so make sure you default `this.state.DataFromApiTemp` to an empty array. so if there is any render happening before the data is loaded. it will log nothing instead of fail

Comment: this.state.DataFromApiTemp.forEach((value, key) => {

  console.log("1-key =>", key, "1-value =>", value.id);
});